# Node express api error - sqlite3 command failed - python2 not recognised

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a node express api running - but I am running into a build error when I try and do an npm install.

I get the following error?

```
"node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   unpack_sqlite_dep
npm ERR!   'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR!   operable program or batch file."
```

Is this an outdated version or package - what fix do I need to make to the package file or command to get the express api running?

===
the package file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "node-express-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Express REST Song API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nw-gyp": "^3.6.5",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

here is the full error log for this.

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1> npm install
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.3 -> 9.6.7
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.7
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.6.7 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   unpack_sqlite_dep
npm ERR!   'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR!   operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for '..\..\deps\sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz' exited with code 1. [C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Derek Mal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@18.12.1 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v108-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.1 found at "C:\Users\Derek Mal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.5.33627.172) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Derek Mal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Derek Mal\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.12.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Derek Mal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:201:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Derek Mal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v108-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v108-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Derek Mal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp64\\www\\Nonone\\_node-application\\v1\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp64\www\Nonone\_node-application\v1\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Try updating to the latest `sqlite3` version (5.1.6). The version you're using is quite old. More info here ~ https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/issues/1552

Comment: I think that was the problem - thank you - I deleted the package lock and ran install again - its alive now - thank you